# Choice of classification loss function with unequal payoffs

Tags: classification, predictive-models, loss-functions

Suppose that I'm building a binary classifier parameterized by $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^k$ that maps some observed features $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^l$ to a decision of whether or not to play a game with an uncertain payoff:
$$ f(\centerdot;\theta): \mathbb{R}^l \to \{0,1\}.$$
The payoff of the $i$th game is $y_i \sim N(0,1)$ and my objective is to maximize my expected profit after $n$ games:
$$\max_{\theta} \mathrm{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n y_i f(x_i;\theta)\right].$$
The classifier might be a linear model, neural network, etc.

From reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_functions_for_classification, my understanding is that I should construct a loss function that uses the output of a model before discretization.  I imagine the reason is so that there is some sense of "how close was the prediction to reality" rather than a binary right/wrong.  But if I use one of their suggested loss functions, I lose all of the information from the size of the payoff, i.e., misclassifying a tiny payoff is just as bad misclassifying a large payoff.

So my question is why shouldn't I just use my objective function directly as my loss function?  Why are squared loss, cross entropy loss, etc. suggested instead?

Comment: Did you ever figure out an answer to this? I have the same question!

Comment: [This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/346781) on CrossValidated gives some clues.

Comment: I do not understand your question. I see two possibilities: (1) $y_i$ is known before you decide to play. If you play, you win $y_i$ (which could be negative) and win $0$ if you don't play. So just play depending on whether $y_i>0$. (2) $y_i$ is *not* known before you play. You don't know the payoff. But it is symmetric around zero. So whether you play or not makes no difference. You will break even in expectation. Altogether, I am rather obviously not understanding something. Voting to close as unclear, please clarify.

Comment: I think you misread the Wikipedia article, because at the outset it makes it clear that the loss encodes the "price paid for inaccuracy of predictions."  It doesn't prescriptively declare that the loss functions it describes are the ones you "should" use: it offers them only as common examples where all misclassifications have the same costs.